# Confidence of a sample belonging to a distribution

Tags: classification, normal-distribution

Lets say, I am trying to Identify a particular fish in a lake using aspect ratio (lets assume that it has discriminatory abilities, and isn't central to the question being asked). I have estimated the ratio from multiple images of a video (this is why I am using aspect ration rather than absolute measurements) and have a mean and standard deviation (assuming gaussian distribution) If I later observe a fish with a certain aspect ratio, what is the probability that they had the same aspect ratio? What are the ways I can characterise it?

In my particular case, the new fish observed was within one standard deviation. How do I translate it to something similar to confidence and say something along the lines of "80% chance that its the same fish."

Comment: If you want to assign probabilities to a classification task you may want to take a Bayesian approach.

Comment: @Glen_b good point. Since the OP was talking about confidence, I thought he was just rephrasing NHST the layman's way (the wrong way). If he really  is interested in computing the probability is null is false ( or true: same thing), then he must go the Bayesian way, as you note. If he wants a procedure which, when the two fishes have the same aspect ratio, gives the correct answer $(1-\alpha)\%$ of times, then my answer applies.

Answer (score 1):

I'd define your experiment better. First of all, you need to calibrate your measurement system by taking videos of specimens of known aspect ratio (a/r). If you haven't done that, I'm pretty sure you can say *nothing at all* about the (allegedly) new fish you observed: statistics is no substitute for poor experimental practices. Secondly, the only hypothesis you can test is that the two fishes have the same a/r: this is not the same as testing whether they're the same fish or not (I and my cousin may have the same a/r, but we're not the same person). However, if you refute the hypothesis that the two fishes have the same a/r, you can also refute the hypothesis they're the same fish (unless of course it grew/shrank between a set of measurements and the other :-) ).

Assuming you have calibrated your system, you now have multiple measurements (corrected for acquisition system bias, drift, effect of medium properties and whatsnot) of a continuous variable (a/r) for a single subject. I assume measurements are normally distributed: I think that's a reasonable assumption for multiple measurements of the same quantity from a calibrated measurement system. However, I'm not an expert on calibration of measurement instruments/systems, so you may want to read the relevant literature or consult an expert (maybe an experimental physicist?).

What I would do now, would be to get *multiple measurements* of the new fish (which may or may not be the same fish). You now have two independent samples form normal populations, and you can test the hypothesis that the two samples come form the same population. This is a classic two samples $t$-test, and more or less any stats software allows you to perform it. For example, in R you can use the `t.test()` function.

Note that the result of the test will only tell you whether the two sets of measurements are compatible with the hypothesis that they come from the same population, i.e., that the two fishes have the same a/r. If the test doesn't refute the hypothesis, you cannot say that the two fishes have the same a/r: you can only say that you failed to refute the hypothesis that the two fishes have the same a/r. They may have different a/r, but the difference may be too small for your test to detect it, at that sample size and confidence level.